# Do we have an event when Drawing Mode changes in google maps?

Tags: draw

I would like to have an event before drawing the overlays using drawing tool (polygon).  In the event, I would like to clear any previous drawings.

Answer (score 1):

We can listen changes and then get mode.

```
    drawingManager.addListener( "drawingmode_changed", function() {
      console.log("drawingmode_changed", drawingManager.getDrawingMode());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In coffeescript

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener mapElement, 'click', (e) ->  
  if e?.target?.parentElement?.parentElement?.parentElement?.title == "Draw a shape"
    clearExistingShapes() # <-- your own code goes there
```

Not very elegant, but it works in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

No :(

Hopefully in the future. Stable release is 3.32 at time of writing